error fetching Parameter from AWS parameter store Error: connect ECONNREFUSED XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443
I am fetching values from AWS Parameter store and AWS Secret manager in my Node js application.
I am using these two dependencies -
@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager", "@aws-sdk/client-ssm"
I recently updated both of these dependencies from version 3.321.1, 3.332.0 respectively to 3.556.0.
Since the update I have been seeing the following error -
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '51.120.196.222:443',
  port: 443,
  '$metadata': { attempts: 3, totalRetryDelay: 200 }
}

This error occurs every time the application is newly deployed, but once the code tries to fetch parameters again after this attempt (and the first 3 default retries), the connection is successful.
Could someone please tell me what could be causing this?
More info -
Node version used by my application - v14.17.3
Code for fetching the parameters -
`const parameterStoreClient = new SSMClient({region: 'us-east-1'})

 const command = new GetParameterCommand( {Name:param_store_path});

 let param;

 async function runParams() {
    try {
      param = await parameterStoreClient.send(command);
       const {Parameter: {Value}} = param;
       return JSON.parse(Value);
    }
    catch(error){
    console.log("error fetching Parameter from parameter store", error)
    }
  }

I have gone through the release notes of all the minor version between the old and new versions I don't see anything related to this issues.
Could someone please help me identify whats causing this or suggest any fix for this?
